# Zookeeper auto-purge does not work

Tags: apache-zookeeper

After around 6 months of using zookeeper in develop phase, though it works fine but the size of its data directory grew up to **6 GIG**! and it is still increasing. Some of the system specifications are listed below:

> zookeeper version: 3.4.6
>   number of clients: < 10
>   number of znodes: < 400
>   also ...
>   there are 90 log.* files in dataDir/version-2
>   there is no snapshot.* file in dataDir/version-2 !

Searching through google for this problem I found auto-purge option in [Advanced Configuration](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_advancedConfiguration) section of the `ZooKeeper Administrator's Guide` page. Then I rolled zookeeper out using the following conifguration (zoo.cfg):

> tickTime=2000
>       dataDir=/home/faghani/software/zookeeper/zkdata
>       clientPort=2181
>       authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
>       requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
>       **autopurge.snapRetainCount=3**
>       **autopurge.purgeInterval=1**

But no change was occurred even when `purgeInterval` got many times expired, i.e. still the size of zookeeper data directory is 6G and no file was deleted. Here is a `ls -laht` on `${dataDir}/version-2`. There is a strange point here, `Nautilus` says that the size of data directory is 6G but `ls -laht` says it is just 3.4G!

```
faghani@node255:~/software/zookeeper/zkdata/version-2$ ls -laht  
total 3.4G  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faghani faghani  65M Dec 20 10:09 log.1061d  
drwx------ 2 faghani faghani 4.0K Dec 20 10:09 .  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faghani faghani  65M Dec 19 17:28 log.105f2  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faghani faghani  65M Dec 15 18:37 log.105c1  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faghani faghani  65M Dec 14 16:17 log.105bc  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faghani faghani  65M Dec  9 18:08 log.10576  
drwx------ 3 faghani faghani 4.0K Dec  9 16:57 ..    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faghani faghani  65M Dec  9 16:56 log.10565
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faghani faghani  65M Dec  8 18:31 log.1048c
and many more until ...  
-rw------- 1 faghani faghani  65M Sep  2 16:41 log.1d03
```

Also the following command (as suggested in [Maintenance](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance) section) made no effect on the files in data directory.

```
java -cp zookeeper.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:conf org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog <dataDir> <snapDir> -n <count>
```

By the way, I found [this question](http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/auto-purge-not-purging-td7579221.html) but unfortunately there is no solution for it in that page.

Questions:

1- Where are the snapshot.* files?
2- If SASL settings can hinder auto-purging? (I think no)
3- Is something gone wrong in configuration?

**EDIT:** It seems that the solution is something around the **snapCount** property. Default value of this property is 100000, just decrease it to a very small number, e.g. 10, and test the system.

Answer (score 5):

You can use that ***zkCleanup.sh*** script which is inside the source folder (`./bin` sub-folder). In case you can't find it, you can find it [here](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/bin/zkCleanup.sh). The usage of this script:

```
zkCleanup.sh <snapshotDir> -n <count>
for example:
# ./zkCleanup.sh /tmp/zookeeper -n 6
```

`<snapshotDir>` is the zookeeper snapshot files location, in my case, my snapshot files are in folder `/tmp/zookeeper/version-2/`

`<count>` is the retained log & snapshot file numbers, The value of `<count>` should typically be greater than 3.

For more details, you can refer this document: [Ongoing Data Directory Cleanup](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#Ongoing+Data+Directory+Cleanup).

This can be run as a cron job on the ZooKeeper server machines to clean up the logs daily. In my case, I clean up one time every week:

```
0 7 * * 0 ( cd /root/otter/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin && ./zkCleanup.sh /tmp/zookeeper -n 5 ) >> /tmp/zookeeper/cron.log 2>&1
```

You can add this by `crontab -e` but remember to change the frequency according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is directly related to running ZK with Solr then it would be useful to read the following email chain in Solr's mail list: [Auto purge for ZK transaction logs in Solr](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/auto-purge-for-embedded-zookeeper-td4275561.html).

In a nutshell Solr has embedded ZK running through their own `SolrZKServer` which doesn't take into account `autopurge.snapRetainCount=3` nor 
`autopurge.purgeInterval=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful info, Running below command worked for me [zookeeper version: 3.5.5]. Ref https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperTools.html#zkCleanup

```
zkCleanup.sh -n 5
```

zKCleanup script is present in zookeeper bin folder. [/apache-zookeeper-3.5.5-bin/bin]

Autopurge variable info can be found at :
https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_advancedConfiguration